# Running UF-B along the outside wall of the house

Tags: electrical

I want to run an outdoor cable to an outside outlet box without burying the cable. My location is upstate NY, USA.

Here is the circuit description:
120v/30a CB feeding #10/2 UF-B cable to an outdoor outlet (this is for an RV hookup on the side of the house.

I am interested in coming out of the wall with the UF-B, attaching it to the side of the house(about 2ft above the ground) to the outdoor box. The run along the side of the house is about 30ft.

Will code allow this run without conduit? If not what is code requirement.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Gene

Comment: Is your UF-B cable marked "Sunlight Resistant" on its jacket?

Comment: Yes, "Sunlight Resistant" printed on it.

Answer (score 1):

Since your UF cable is marked "Sunlight Resistant", you can run it outdoors aboveground without protecting it from the sun's rays.  Go ahead and make the run -- just make sure the cable isn't in a position where it could get weedwhacked, run over, or otherwise physically damaged.

If it is, you'll need to protect the run with a length of conduit.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Please don't be offended, but are you a licensed electrician?

Comment: @Gene -- far closer to a Code-knowledgeable EE.

Comment: Without seeing where this is being installed, you can't say for sure that no protection is required.   Type UF cable is not permitted where subject to physical damage.  Based on the information provided, there's no way for you to know if protection is required.

Comment: what more info would you like?

Comment: Tester101, unless you let me know what else you would like to know then I have no choice but to overlook your comment